# Recording SSH sessions on linux using Python

Tags: python, ssh

I need to record all SSH activity in Linux using Python. Are there examples in python on how to capture entire remote SSH sessions?

I need to capture them and store them.

I would appreciate any help.

Thanks,
Sarah

Comment: What kind of activity do you want to record? Do you want to record outgoing or incoming connections?

Comment: No, I want to record everything typed on the terminal / console and SSH

Answer (score 1):

Try `script`. It's a built-in Linux command that records everything that happens on an interactive console to a file.

Usage is simple: `script [log filename] [command] [args...]`. As an example:

```
$ script ssh_log ssh remotehost
Script started, output file is ssh_log
remotehost:~$ logout
Script done, output file is ssh_log
$ cat ssh_log
remotehost:~$ logout
```

Comment: Thank you for this one...but I need this in python because I need the stored data to be encrypted.